# Search for text ignoring and combining white string in Mongo DB Text Search & Regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, search, text, full-text-search

Database:

```
{title: "Honda CBR500"},
{title: "Honda CBR500R"},
{title: "Honda CBR 500R"},
{title: "Honda CBR 500 R"},
{title: "Honda CBR 250 R"},
```

I would like that my MongoDB Text Search returns all these results instead of an exact match when looking for "**CBR**" for example and also all result except "CBR 250" when looking for "**CBR500**".

Currently (default mongo text search behavior) if I look for "**CBR500**" I only get:

```
{title: "Honda CBR500"}
```

Instead of

```
{title: "Honda CBR500"},
{title: "Honda CBR500R"},
{title: "Honda CBR 500R"},
{title: "Honda CBR 500 R"}
```

I was thinking of adding an additional field for example normalised_title and use regex to split words such as CBR500R into keywords example :

```
{title: "Honda CBR500", normalised_title: "CBR 500"},
{title: "Honda CBR500R", normalised_title: "CBR 500 R CBR500 500R},
{title: "Honda CBR 500R", normalised_title: "CBR500R CBR 500 CBR 500 R"},
{title: "Honda CBR 500 R", normalised_title: "CBR 500R CBR 500 R"},
{title: "Honda CBR 250 R", normalised_title: "CBR250R CBR 250 R 250R"}}
```

This would enable me to make a combined text search and return all when I look for CBR as well as return all when using CBR 500 (then sort by score and get the 250s at the bottom)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would really slow down the search I'm afraid. I'm not 100% sure that's possible with mongo but may have to fall back to it if I don't find a scalable solution. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Also CBR could be anything really. any 1 to 4 digits such as "Subaru J10"  and "Subaru J 10"

Comment: Unfortunately, you are short of options here with full text search. It's mongodb stemming process which eliminates stop words and thinks CBR and CBR500 are two different words. However, you can use normal regex to achieve same solution but with less than ideal performance. e.g.

`db.cars.find({title:/CBR|500/ig})` will return all documents with title containing word `CBR or 500` in your case, all five documents are you mentioned above

Comment: @sln, regex is quite slow unless we are matching start of words .e.g `/^(HONDA)/` will be fast but `/CBR/` will not as regex has to search full string for possibilities.

Comment: I'll explain you. let's assume you have a string of 100 words and normal regex has to search some text into it.  it's possible that regex find this word in beginning of string or even at end.
When desired word is fond in beginning of string, it will be much faster as compared to one who is found at end of string. regardless of what language you use, this holds true.

Comment: essentially, in case of regex, mongodb do full document scan but in case of full text search (text index), it's just index and index traversal is much faster than full document and collection scan.